# How to display related items in starlette-admin?

Tags: python, django-admin, fastapi, admin, starlette

I want to display related items using starlette-admin, but i'm new to this, don't understand what part i should change.
For example, I have `orm.py`:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from models.tables import Base, theme_table, post_table, comment_table


class Theme(Base):
    __table__ = theme_table


class Post(Base):
    __table__ = post_table

    theme = relationship(Theme)


class Comment(Base):
    __table__ = comment_table

    theme = relationship(Theme)
```

`admin_panel.py`:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from starlette_admin.contrib.sqla import Admin, ModelView
from models.orm import Theme, Comment, Post

def init_admin(app):
    engine = create_engine("sqlite:///test.db", connect_args={"check_same_thread": False})
    admin = Admin(
        engine,
        base_url='/test/admin',
        title='Test Admin'
    )
    class ThemeAdmin(ModelView):
        name = 'Theme'
        label = 'Themes'

     class PostAdmin(ModelView):
        name = 'Post'
        label = 'Posts'
    
    class CommentAdmin(ModelView):
        name = 'Comment'
        label = 'Comments'
```

I want to display all posts, comments (with links) on detail theme page. For example, if i open theme with id = 1, i want to display all posts, where theme_id = 1, etc. I want to save starlette-admin style, just extend the pattern. I want to display it on table, like usual attributes.

I will be really thankful for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You need add primary key in main table and foreign key and relationship in sub table.

```
class MainTable(Base):
    __table__ = "main_table"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class SubTable(Base):
    __table__ = "sub_table"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    main_id = Column(ForeignKey("main_table.id"))
    rel = relationship("MainTable")



class SubTableView(ModelView):
    fields = ["id", "rel"]
```